# Stop pandoc adding id automatically

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I am using [Pandoc's extention of markdown](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#pandocs-markdown) to produce HTML.

The following markdown:

```
#test{#specificId}
##test2
###test3
```

Produces the following html

```
<h1 id="specificId">test</h1>
<h2 id="test2">test2</h2>
<h3 id="test3">test3</h3>
```

Ideally, It would produce this:

```
<h1 id="specificId">test</h1>
<h2>test2</h2>
<h3>test3</h3>
```

I couldn't find an option in the documentation that would make the output only add an ID if it was explicitly added to the markdown although I don't really know what to search for.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer.

The "feature" is called `auto_identifiers`.  It can be disabled in the command by changing `-f markdown` to `-f markdown-auto_identifiers`

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Thanks, Johnathan. Any chance you could elaborate on where exactly you are making this change?

Comment: @BryanMichael while calling it: `pandoc -f markdown-auto_identifiers -t html -o foo.html foo.md`, where `-f` is a shorthand for `--from`.