# Xaringan in Rmarkdown: How to remove auto_identifiers in headings

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

While there seems to be quite a bit of discussion about this ([here](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58785061/how-to-remove-anchor-links-from-headers-in-markdown), [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1407)), it is not clear how one could remove the section heading `auto_identifiers` (the "#" that appears after a slide's section header; `h1`,`h2`,etc.) from a Xaringan theme in Rmarkdown.

Can this be done within the YAML? (`markdown: kramdown` seems to have an `auto_ids: false` addition to the header as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58785061/how-to-remove-anchor-links-from-headers-in-markdown))

Can this be done in a `custom.css` by editing `.h1` etc.?

Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43717234/stop-pandoc-adding-id-automatically):

If the headers are specified as:

```
# header1 {#header1id}
## header2
### header3
```

The resulting HTML:

```
<h1 id="header1id">header1</h1>
<h2 id="header2">header2</header2>
<h3 id="header3">header3</header3>
```

But I would prefer:

```
<h1 id="header1id">header1</h1>
<h2>header2</h2>
<h3>header3</h3>
```

Obviously, using the html directly works (e.g., `<h1>header1</h1>`), but it would be great to be able to use the markdown `#` headers.

For completeness, an example YAML within a `Rmarkdown.Rmd` Xaringan template:

```
---
title: "Please Remove the # Anchors"
author: "Begin Er"
date: "Now"
output: 
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: [default, metropolis, metropolis-fonts]
    nature: 
      beforeInit: "macros.js"
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
      ratio: "16:9"
---
```

Thanks!